# Develop Graph on J2ME

Tags: graph, canvas, java-me

I going to develop Graph on my j2me application. I have taken Canvas & I wann to draw graph on particular data then how  i can draw graph ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the paint() method. See Ch 9 of "Kicking Butt with MIDP and MSA" by Jonathon Knudsen ([http://www.amazon.com/Kicking-Butt-MIDP-MSA-Applications/dp/0321463420](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321463420))